# Strange Result in Contour Integration: Possible Mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

**(Context)** I tried out this proof I made up for fun:

**Let $a \geq 0.$ Prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-\sin\left(ax\right)\right)\sin\left(\cos\left(ax\right)\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx = \pi\sin\left(\frac{1}{e^{a}}\right).$$**

I put this integral and my answer in Desmos with a slider $a$, and it seems like Desmos is numerically approximating both expressions such that they're both off by a bit, probably around $0.1$ or $0.01$. (Also, I was treating $\infty$ as a huge number like $3000$ because Desmos sometimes has trouble dealing with it.)

**(Attempt)** Let that integral equal $I$. Rewriting it gives us

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(-\sin\left(ax\right)\right)\sin\left(\cos\left(ax\right)\right)}{x^{2}+1}dx = \Im \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp\left(ie^{iaz}\right)}{z^{2}+1}dz.$$

Let $f(z) = \frac{\exp\left(ie^{iaz}\right)}{z^{2}+1}$ and traverse counterclockwise along this curve $C:= \left[-R,R\right] \cup \Gamma$, where $C$ is a semicircle on and above the real axis in the complex plane and $R$ is a large radius approaching $\infty$. The set of singularities is $\left\{i,-i\right\}$ (after setting the denominator equal to $0$).

Notice that $i$ lives in $C$, so we can make it our pole. By Cauchy's Residue Theorem, we can rewrite $\oint_C f(z)dz$ as

$$2\pi i\text{Res}(f(z), z=i) = \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \int_{-R}^R f(z)dz.$$

Solving the residue, we get

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\exp\left(ie^{iaz}\right)}{z^{2}+1}, z=i\right) = \frac{\exp{(ie^{ia(i)})}}{\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^2+1\right)\Big|_{z=i}} = \frac{\exp\left(ie^{-a}\right)}{2i}.$$

As for the contour integral, it converges to $0$ as $R \to \infty$. Notice if $z$ is on $\Gamma$, then $|z| = R$. Observe from using one of the Triangle Inequalities that

$$\left|\frac{\exp\left(ie^{iaz}\right)}{z^{2}+1}\right|\le\frac{\left|\exp\left(ie^{iaz}\right)\right|}{\left|\left|z\right|^{2}-1\right|}=\frac{1}{R^{2}-1}.$$

Using the ML-Inequality, observe that

$$0 \leq \left|\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz\right| \leq |f(z)|\left(\frac{2\pi R}{2}\right) \leq \frac{\pi R}{R^2-1}.$$

Taking $R\to\infty$, we can use the Squeeze Theorem to get

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\left|\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz\right| = 0,$$

which implies

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz = 0.$$

Going back to $\oint_{C} f(z)dz$, we take $R\to\infty$ and $\Im$ on both sides to get

$$
\eqalign{
\Im\lim_{R\to\infty} 2\pi i\text{Res}(f(z), z=i) &= \Im\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz + \Im\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^R f(z)dz   \cr
\Im\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}f(z)dz &= I \cr
&= \Im\left(\pi \exp{\left(ie^{-a}\right)}\right) \cr
&= \pi\sin{\left(\frac{1}{e^a}\right)}. \cr
}
$$

**(Question)** Is there something wrong with my proof? I've checked this over and over and I want to say there's nothing wrong and that I didn't miss anything trivial. Still, the approximations Desmos is giving me are sort of bothering me, even though I know Desmos isn't always reliable when evaluating things at $\infty$. And also, the proof doesn't seem to hold true if $a$ is negative. If my proof is correct, then how come it breaks when $a$ is negative?

If someone can shed some light, that would be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have $\left|\exp(ie^{iaz})\right|=1$. It is only true for $z$ real.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm still confused. I got that it's equal to $\exp{\left(-\Im\left(e^{iaz}\right)\right)}$. Since $z \in \Gamma$, that means $z = iR$. I plugged in $iR$ yet I'm still getting $1$ as my answer.

Comment: My apology - made a mistake in the previous comment. The correct evaluation: along the path $\Gamma\,\,z=Re^{i\phi}=R\cos\phi+iR\sin\phi$
$$\exp{\big(ie^{iaz}}\big)=\exp{\big(ie^{iaR\cos\phi-aR\sin\phi}}\big)=\exp{\Big[i(\cos(aR\cos\phi)+i\sin(aR\cos\phi))e^{-aR\sin\phi}\big)\Big]}$$
$$=\exp \big(i\cos(aR\cos\phi )e^{-aR\sin\phi}\big)\exp(-\sin(aR\cos\phi)e^{-aR\sin\phi}\big)$$
$$\Big|\exp{\big(ie^{iaz}}\big)\Big|=\exp(-\sin(aR\cos\phi)e^{-aR\sin\phi}\big)$$

Comment: For $a>0$ we close the contour in the upper half-plane ($\phi\in[0;\pi]$). Then $e^{-aR\sin\phi}\to 0$ at $R\to\infty$, and $\Big|\exp{\big(ie^{iaz}}\big)\Big|\to 1$. For $a<0$ we close the contour in the lower half-plane ($\phi\in[0;-\pi]$), and get the residue at $z=-i$ (in this case we go in the negative direction, so we get an additional minus). In both cases the answer is $\pi\sin e^{-|a|}$, as it should be (the integral is invariant under the change $a\to-a$).

Comment: @Svyatoslav That makes perfect sense. I think I understand everything. I didn't think of parameterizing $z$ like how you did it. Thank you very much for your patience in tying all that!

Comment: Interesting corollary:
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_z^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\big(-\sin(tx)\big)\sin\big(\cos(tx)\big)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx\mathrm dt=\operatorname{Si}(\mathrm e^{-z})$$
Where Si is the sine integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your proof except that you have the incorrect upper bound on the magnitude of $ \exp \left(ie^{iaz} \right) $ in the upper half-plane.

While $\left| \exp \left(ie^{iaz} \right) \right|,  \, a\ge 0, $ can exceed $1$ in the upper half-plane, it will never exceed $e$.

Let $z= x +iy$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y >0$.

Then since $a \ge 0$ we have

$$ \begin{align} \left| \exp \left(ie^{iaz} \right) \right| &= \left| \exp \left(ie^{ia(x+iy)} \right) \right| \\ &=\left|\exp \left(i \left( \cos(ax) + i \sin(ax)\right)e^{-ay} \right) \right| \\ &= \left|\exp \left(i \cos(ax) e^{-ay} \right) \right| \exp \left( -\sin(ax) e^{-ay} \right)\\ &= \exp \left(-\sin(ax) e^{-ay} \right) \\  &\le \exp \left(e^{-ay} \right) \\ &\le \exp(1). \end{align}$$

On the other hand, if $a<0$, then there is no upper bound on the magnitude of $\exp \left(ie^{iaz} \right)$ in the upper half-plane.