# Can we show: $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin\cos\tan x\cosh\sin\tan x\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\sin(1/e)$ with contours?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, contour-integration

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$By converting $\sin,\cos$ into their exponential forms and expanding the exponential into a series, it can be quickly shown using “normal” techniques that: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\cos x\cosh\sin x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1/e)$$Which is equivalent to:

> $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin\cos\tan(\vartheta)\cosh\sin\tan(\vartheta)\d\vartheta=\pi\cdot\sin(1/e)$$

This *seems* amenable to using contour integration (this approach is harder but of mathematical and - for me - educational interest). A notable complication is that this integral is improper. If we pass to $z=e^{it}$, we must also take an improper contour integral, i.e:

> For $\varepsilon>0$ small, let $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$ be the contour $t\mapsto e^{it}$ restricted to $[\varepsilon-\pi/2,\pi/2-\varepsilon]$. Then it suffices to show: $$2\pi i\cdot\sin(1/e)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\oint_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}2\sin\cosh\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\cos\sinh\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{z}\d z$$We can use $\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)=2\sin(a)\cos(b)$ and $\cosh(x)+\sinh(x)=e^x,\,\cosh(x)-\sinh(x)=e^{-x}$ and instead ask to show:

> $$2\pi i\cdot\sin(1/e)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\oint_{\gamma_{\varepsilon}}\frac{\sin(\exp(r(z)))+\sin(\exp(-r(z)))}{z}\d z=:\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}J_{\varepsilon}$$Where $r(z)=1-2(1+z^2)^{-1}$.

What is promising about this: if one were to close the contour in such a way that it winds once around the origin, then the integral would evaluate to $2\pi i[\sin(e)+\sin(1/e)]$ by the residue theorem, $r(0)=-1$. The standard thing to do here might be to add the contours $\gamma_{\pm}:[0,\pi]\to\Bbb C$, $t\mapsto\pm i\mp\varepsilon e^{it}$. Then: $$J_{\varepsilon}=2\pi i[\sin(1/e)+\sin(e)]+\oint_{\gamma_+\cup\,\gamma_-}$$So we “just” need to show:

> $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\oint_{\gamma_+\cup\,\gamma_-}\frac{\sin\exp(r(z))+\sin\exp(-r(z))}{z}\d z=-2\pi i\cdot\sin(e)$$Furthermore, $r$ is even and $\gamma_+(t)=-\gamma_-(t)$ so  this symmetry allows us to instead show: $$\tag{$\ast$}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0+}\oint_{\gamma_+}\frac{\sin\exp(r(z))+\sin\exp(-r(z))}{z}\d z\overset{?}{=}-\pi i\cdot\sin(e)$$

But this is very difficult (for me). Substituting $z=\gamma_{\pm}(t)$ gives a very ugly mess. The asymptotics of the integrand are essentially $\sin\exp(O(\varepsilon^{-2}))$ and upon expansion into real and imaginary parts, we get a mess of $\sin(a)\cosh(b)+\cdots$ where $b=\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdot)))$ (more or less) and the asymptotics of *that* seem intractable. Equally, I might be overthinking this and getting lost in irrelevant details.

A realised (?) version of our goal:

> $$\pi\cdot\sin(e)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\varepsilon\cdot\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\exp\left(1+\frac{2}{\varepsilon\cdot e^{it}(2i-\varepsilon\cdot e^{it})}\right)+\sin\exp\left(-1-\frac{2}{\varepsilon\cdot e^{it}(2i-\varepsilon\cdot e^{it})}\right)}{i\cdot e^{-it}-\varepsilon}\d t$$

The question: does anyone know how to continue, i.e. how to successfully show $(\ast)$? I’d really like to learn from this, as an example of more advanced asymptotic analysis than I’m used to. But perhaps it really is too difficult: in which case, I’d be happy to see alternative contour methods.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you interested in such a not-very-natural integral (personal opinion, I confess) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It certainly isn't very natural. But, I saw it online, and I think that the overall aesthetic of: $$\int\sin\cos\tan\cdot\cosh\sin\tan=\pi\sin(1/e)$$Is nice

Comment: @JeanMarie But also - if this question gets an answer, I would learn a lot from that answer

Comment: [Related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527179/strange-result-in-contour-integration-possible-mistake#comment9514144_4527179)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to deal with the integral in its original form.

The magnitude of  $$ \begin{align} \sin(e^{iz}) &= \sin \left( e^{i(x+iy)} \right) \\ &= \sin \left((e^{-y}\cos(x) \right)\cosh\left( e^{-y}\sin(x) \right)+i \cos\left( e^{-y}\cos(x) \right)\sinh\left( e^{-y} \sin(x)\right) \end{align} $$  never gets large in the upper half-plane.  It only gets large in the lower half-plane.

More precisely, we can say that in the upper half-plane, $$|\sin(e^{iz})| \le \sqrt{\cosh^{2}(1)+ \sinh^{2}(1)} <2.$$

Therefore, we can integrate around a semicircular contour in the upper half-plane and conclude that $$ \begin{align} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\cos x)\cosh(\sin x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx &=\frac{1}{2} \, \Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(e^{ix})}{1+x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx \\ & = \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \, 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{\sin(e^{iz})}{1+z^{2}}, i \right] \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \, \sin(1/e). \end{align} $$

Comment: Thanks for this. In your experience, would you say that the nasty limit I pose in my question is intractable / too difficult to reasonably sit down and calculate?

Comment: @FShrike It seems intractable to me, but I can't say for sure that it actually is.